# Getting Sound Activated on Portable Monitor (Linux)

Tags: linux, audio, multiple-monitors

I've connected [a portable monitor](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0BGRRZT8T) to my Linux machine via a DisplayPort (on my computer) to HDMi (on the monitor) cable.

**Problem:** The monitor works just fine, but I can't get sound to work on it.

- When I launch `pavucontrol` in Linux, I don't see the monitor in the list of output devices.
- Sound works just fine  on my two other monitors I also have hooked up to my machine (each of these monitors is acting as a mirror of the primary one).

Any idea on what the issue could be?

Comment: Although the displayport specification technically supports audio, many implementations that I have seen only carry audio through HDMI.  I am guessing that it has more to do with that HDMI/DisplayPort crossover cable than anything else.  Of course this is only a guess.  See [this](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2273039-no-sound-displayport-to-hdmi-cable) as I am not the only one to suspect the cable.